# Why can I only get the Audio Input of the "primary/standard" audio device?

Tags: java, audio

I have written a java program to get the audio Input of a selected audio device. It only works for the primary/standard audio device (primary/standard selected in Operation System).

`start();` starts the audio input streaming:

```
public void run() {

    while (continueLoop) {

        n = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);

        updateMeter();

        try {
            Object_Output_Stream.writeObject(tempBuffer);
            Object_Output_Stream.reset();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            continueLoop = false;
        }
    }

}
```

If I try to select another audio source it only returns noise. Can anyone tell me why?

```
if (e.getSource() == combo1) {
    System.out.println("Gewählter Input: " + combo1.getSelectedItem());

    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
        Mixer currentMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[cnt]);

        if (mixerInfo[cnt].getName() == combo1.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
            System.out.println("Gewählter Input gefunden");

            if ( !first_time) {

                if (targetDataLine.isRunning())
                    targetDataLine.stop();

                if (targetDataLine.isOpen())
                    targetDataLine.close();
            }
            dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getAudioFormat());
            try {
                targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) currentMixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
                targetDataLine.open(getAudioFormat());
                targetDataLine.start();

                if (first_time) {
                    start();
                    first_time = false;
                }

            } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set microphone device more sensitive?...

Comment: No the level of microphone is not the problem. If I select another audio device as primary in my OS then it works fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo I spended days of headache to find the java bug and now it turns out it was a windows bug. The code works on another pc perfectly...